# How can i transfer APK files from my old SD card to a new micro SD card?

Tags: apk, app2sd

I just bought a 32GB micro SD card to replace my 8GB micro SD card for my x10. I have some apps that I've downloaded online (paid APK) and not from the market. They are currently stored in my 8GB micro SD.  I don't know how to transfer the files to the new 32GB card.  I don't know in what folder they should be placed in. Again, my unit is an SE x10 (eclair).

Answer (score 5):

1. Connect your x10 to your computer with the old 8gb car installed and enable usb debugging
2. With your PCs file manager copy the entire contents of your x10's SD card to a temporary folder.
3. Change the cards so the 32gb is installed.
4. Copy the entire contents of the temp folder onto the new microSD.

It will be an exact mirror of what you had before.

Comment: Exactly, there's no reason to pull things out of folders.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the APK itself to reinstall the app. Create a temporary folder on your new SD card, you can call it anything you like (such as "APK-Install") and copy the APKs into there.

When you plug the new SD card, use a file manager (download something like "[ASTRO File Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/astro-file-manager/com.metago.astro)" if you haven't got one already) and browse to that folder. Now if you run that APK file it should give you the option to install the app. (I assume that you've already enabled the "Allow install of non-Market applications" option as you say that you've loaded non-Market apps before).

You're running Eclair, so (unless you've rooted) I assume that you haven't moved any of your installed apps to the SD card, but if you have remember to move them back into internal memory before you swap cards.

Comment: This is an unnecessary step. He shouldn't have to re-install the apps after replacing the SD.  If he copys the old SD card completely to the new one, the previously installed apps on the SD card will continue to function as before.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want to move the data from the old card to the new one...

Before you replace your old sdcard, connect your device to your computer via USB cable and mount the sdcard so your computer can access the data. Now copy all the data from the sdcard to your computer.

Once that is complete, put in the new sdcard and then mount the new sdcard. Now you can copy the data from your old sdcard (now stored on your desktop) to your new sdcard.

After you copy the data to the new sdcard, unmount it. Then you can use a file manager like Astro, to install them using the apk file as GAThrawn stated...